# Bound on the number of p-groups for fixed exponent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

It's [well-known](http://www.math.kth.se/~boij/kandexjobbVT11/Material/pgroups.pdf) that for each prime number $p$ there are exactly two groups of order $p^2$, five of order $p^3$, and fifteen of order $p^4$ (at least when $p>3$).

I know that the classification of $p$-groups gets much harder for higher exponents. But I wonder if $p$-groups with higher dimensions are still structured enough that they would at least theoretically allow a classification.

In particular: *Is there, for every natural $n$, a prime $p_0(n)$ and a number $m(n)$ such that for every $p \ge p_0(n)$ the number of groups of order $p^n$ equals $m(n)$?*

(For example, $m(2)=2,m(3)=5,m(4)=15$ for $p_0(2)=p_0(3)=2$ $p_0(4)=5$.)

Comment: The wikipedia page for [p-groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group#Among_groups) has asymptotics, but it seems no formula is known. I would be surprised if the existence of a formula is known but not the formula itself.

Edit: In fact, since the asymptotics depend on $p$ I think such a $p_0$ cannot exist for large $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. For $n \ge 5$ the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order $p^n$ increases with $p$.

The Higman PORC conjecture (polynomial on residue classes)  is that, for large enough $p$, this number is a polynomial function of $p$, and of the value of $p$ modulo $n_p$ for some finite number of constants $n_p$. For example, for $n=5$ and $p \ge 5$, the number of groups is

$2p + 61 + 2 \gcd(p-1, 3) + \gcd(p-1, 4)$.

The PORC conjecture has been proved for $n=5,6,7$, but is open for $n=8$.

Recent work of Vaughan-Lee and du Sautoy suggests that the conjecture is likely to be false for large $n$. See
[users.ox.ac.uk/~vlee/PORC/porcsurvey.pdf](http://users.ox.ac.uk/~vlee/PORC/porcsurvey.pdf)

Comment: It appears that [newer results](http://www.theoryofgroups.ir/article_5758_1270.html) by Vaughan-Lee settle the case $n=8$.

Comment: Isn't that just for groups of exponent $p$?