# Number of $p$-groups of small order and of exponent $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, groups-enumeration

In a very recent paper of [MR Vaughan-Lee](http://www.theoryofgroups.ir/article_5758_1270.html), it is proved that the number of $p$-groups of order $p^8$ and exponent $p$ is a polynomial (of fourth degree) in $p$.

Let us consider $p$-groups of order $<p^8$ and exponent $p$. I know that 
*the number of $p$-groups of exponent $p$ and order $p$, $p^2$, $p^3$, and $p^4$ is (almost) a constant polynomial in $p$.*

[By  *almost constant*, I mean here, ignoring very few first values of prime $p$, the number of $p$-groups with required property is constant.]

**Question:** What about the number of $p$-groups of order $p^5,p^6,p^7$ and exponent $p$? Is it non-constant polynomial in $p$?

Comment: The accepted answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263876/bound-on-the-number-of-p-groups-for-fixed-exponent?rq=1 states that the number of $p$-groups is (almost) linear in $p$ plus an offset of period $12$. Also it mentions that similar formulas hold for $6$ and $7$

Comment: yes; but, here I am considering *only exponent $p$-groups*; still, it is similar case (i.e. number of p-groups of a fixed order $\geq p^5$ and exponent $p$ increases with $p$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of groups of order $p^7$ and exponent $p$ is
$7p + 174 + 2\gcd(p-1,3)$. See:

https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/p7/paper-p7.pdf

These were first computed by Wilkinson (who was my PhD student many years ago)  [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869388900518), but he made a couple of errors. It is stated in Wilkinson's paper that there are $34$ $p$-groups of exponent $p$ and order $p^6$ for $p \ge 7$. I would guess that it is also a constant for $p^5$.